# why does python treat all the lists declared in the same line as a same object when modifying?

Tags: python, list

In python3 lets say i need to have 3 empty lists.I can assign empty lists separately in 3 separate lines. But the when i declared them in the same line as shown below

**`s1 , s2 , s3 = [[]]*3`**

After doing this whenever i append an element to any **one** of these lists the same element gets appended to all the lists. Its the same with all operations and whenever i pop an item in one list , all the three lists s1 , s2 , s3 pop an item . I can't seam to understand this behaviour

Comment: That is invalid syntax

Comment: it is not work for me (ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
), python3.4

Comment: Maybe you mean something like `s1=s2=s3=[]` , where you've created one list with three names.

Comment: maybe you meant `s1, s2, s3 = [[]]*3` ? anyway, almost certainly you have created only 1 list

Comment: s1, s2, s3 = [[[]] for i in range(3)] for inline initialization your lists

Comment: Edit your code so that it actually runs.

Comment: oops sorry for the typo . It must be mutiplied by 3 . I have edited it now. please take back the downvote if possible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No one actually answered the OP, which was **why** the OP's original syntax (i.e. `s1 , s2 , s3 = [[]]*3`) would treat them all as the same list (i.e. changing one of the lists will change all of them).

## Why are they the same list?

This happens because python lists just make references to things they contain, so the list of a list `[[]]` just points to an empty list. But, when you multiply it by 3, it takes **that same empty list** and refers to it 3 times.

### A Sensible Example

Consider a situation where this would make more intuitive sense. Suppose we already had a list and we **wanted** to repeat that list 3 times:

```
myList = ['me', 'myself', 'Irene']
three_myList = [myList] * 3
three_myList
```

then you get:

```
[['me', 'myself', 'Irene'],['me', 'myself', 'Irene'],['me', 'myself',
'Irene']]
```

but then, if you change a value in the list:

```
myList[2] = 'Tim'
three_myList
```

you get:

```
[['me', 'myself', 'Tim'], ['me', 'myself', 'Tim'], ['me', 'myself', 'Tim']]
```

This makes sense because `three_myList` just references `myList` 3 times over (with a pointer) and `myList` changed. In effect, `three_list` asks for the value of `myList` 3 times, so all 3 references change together.

### Conclusion

In your case, you don't want `s1`, `s2`, and `s3` to refer to the same list, but they do because on the right side of the assignment, you constructed a list that uses the same list three times.

## Different for simple list

But, it's still confusing because a very similar process will cause a different result. Suppose you take a simple list (not nested) and triple it, then it won't update:

```
triple_myList = myList * 3
triple_myList
```

gives:

```
['me', 'myself', 'Tim', 'me', 'myself', 'Tim', 'me', 'myself', 'Tim']
```

but, when you update:

```
myList[2] = 'Irene'
triple_myList
```

The long version doesn't:

```
['me', 'myself', 'Tim', 'me', 'myself', 'Tim', 'me', 'myself', 'Tim']
```

This is because to triple a simple list we had to smash its contents together three times to get another simple (not nested) list. Evaluating this forces a computation that makes a new list. So, `triple_myList` is a new thing that doesn't actually contain `myList` (as an element) and hence doesn't make any references to `myList`.

## Other Commentary

Nick Chapman's answer is actually just another syntax to the get the OP's result in one line, not an explanation of why the OP's syntax works the way it does.

Stan Zeez's comment on the OP explained how to get a different result (3 separate lists that update separately), but he used too many brackets so it creates 3 double-nested lists:

```
s1, s2, s3 = [[[]] for i in range(3)]
s1                     
# [[]]
```

This would create 3 simple lists like the OP did (but these are actually independent, unlike the OP):

```
s1, s2, s3 = [[] for i in range(3)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok assuming that you meant:

```
s1 = s2 = s3 = [[]]
```

The reason that appending to one of them appends to all of the others is because all of them are pointing at the same object. `s2` and `s3` are really just aliases for `s1`. If you want to make deep copies of things then consider looking into the `copy` module: https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html

Comment: or just ×`s1 = [[]]; s2 = [[]]; s3 = [[]]`, which is much more readable (actually each statement should be on a distinct line to be pep08 compliant).

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers yes that is how you would declare 3 separate blank instances. If you want to copy an instance with anything in it, you will need to use some form of copying whether it's from the `copy` module or you use language builtins like `a = b[:]`.